# how to change java version in mac os

Tags: java, macos

My Java version is 15.0.1(default), I want to change it to java 8(1.8.0_281).

I downloaded java8, and tried several things but the version doesn't change..

1. change name of `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Info.plist` to `Info.plist.disabled`
2. change version in ~/.bash_profile and run `source ~/.bash_profile`
3. write `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)` in terminal

I restarted terminal, and run java -version..
but there is still `openjdk version "15.0.1"`

when I write like this, `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` there is no 15.0.1.
It return `1.8.0_281 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home`

In ~/.zshrc, there is no version infomation. just
`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH" export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"`

echo $JAVA_HOME show me `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

How to change java version?? help me plz
(macOs is big sur, 11.2)

Comment: How about `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: @khelwood there is 
/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

Comment: Presumably `java` version 1.8 is in one of those directories.

Comment: In your .bash_profile, is your JAVA_HOME env variable (which you said is pointing to version 8) being appended to PATH (e.g. export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin)? Also, ensure that version 15's bin isn't still on PATH.

Comment: Hint: dont download JDKs manually. Use a package manager like brew.

Answer (score 18):

In mac it's pretty simple you can have two or many java versions and based on your requirement you can change that.

I found a very useful tool called jenv.

If you have already had homebrew (a package installer in mac), you can skip this step.

1. For installing or updating homebrew

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
   ```
2. Installing JEnv - java version manager a cool tool helps you to switch between multiple java env on your mac

   ```
   brew install jenv
   ```
3. Adding jEnv to your path depends on the shell you are using ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc , for zsh it's ~/.zshrc. Add these two lines in your bash profile file

   ```
   export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
   eval "$(jenv init -)"
   ```
4. Restart the terminal or use `source ~/.zshrc`
5. Check if your JEnv is correctly installed

   ```
   jenv doctor
   ```

   you will get the output something like `[OK] Jenv is correctly loaded`
6. for installing java 8

   ```
     brew cask install AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
   ```
7. for installing java 11

   ```
   brew cask install AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk/adoptopenjdk11
   ```
8. for list down all the java on your machine

   ```
   /usr/libexec/java_home -V
   ```
9. Now add these paths to jENV

   ```
   Syntax: 
   jenv add <your_jdk_path>

   Example:
   jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
   ```
10. All done. Check your version

    ```
    jenv versions
    ```
11. For setting system wide java version

    ```
     jenv global 14.0
    ```
12. For setting locally to terminal

    ```
     jenv local 11
    ```
13. if you are using maven or gradle for your project

    ```
      # ensure that JAVA_HOME is correct
      jenv enable-plugin 

      export# make Maven aware of the Java version in use 
      (and switch when your project does)
      jenv enable-plugin maven
    ```

A reference guide
https://www.jenv.be/

Comment: Just a heads up. 
if the `brew cask install AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk/adoptopenjdk11` fails,
replace that command with 
`brew install --cask AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk/adoptopenjdk11`